# Apache Airflow: (v1.10) PythonVirtualenvOperator not working and not sure why

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I'm still working on my first DAG, now moving on to a Python module ...

The task looks like this:

```
TWEAK_TASK = PythonVirtualenvOperator(task_id='tweaker', python_callable=tweaker, requirements=["inflect"], args = ['/home/sem/airflow-data/keywordstep1'],dag=dedup_dag)
```

But it produces this error:

```
[2022-07-27 01:06:44,118] {{taskinstance.py:887}} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonVirtualenvOperator): tweaker> on 2022-07-01T00:00:00+00:00
[2022-07-27 01:06:44,182] {{python_operator.py:316}} INFO - Executing cmd
['virtualenv', '/tmp/venvuwoa1squ', '--system-site-packages']
[2022-07-27 01:06:44,525] {{python_operator.py:321}} INFO - Got output
b'created virtual environment CPython3.7.6.final.0-64 in 202ms\n  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/tmp/venvuwoa1squ, clear=False, global=True)\n  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/sem/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1)\n  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator\n'
[2022-07-27 01:06:44,526] {{python_operator.py:316}} INFO - Executing cmd
['/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/bin/pip', 'install', 'inflect']
[2022-07-27 01:06:48,031] {{python_operator.py:321}} INFO - Got output
b"Collecting inflect\n  Using cached inflect-5.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)\nInstalling collected packages: inflect\nSuccessfully installed inflect-5.6.2\nWARNING: You are using pip version 20.1; however, version 22.2 is available.\nYou should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.\n"
[2022-07-27 01:06:48,040] {{python_operator.py:316}} INFO - Executing cmd
['/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/bin/python', '/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/script.py', '/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/script.in', '/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/script.out', '/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/string_args.txt']
[2022-07-27 01:06:48,121] {{python_operator.py:323}} INFO - Got error output
b'/home/sem/msc-dataflow/data_pipelines/keyword\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/script.py", line 94, in <module>\n    res = tweaker(*args, **kwargs)\n  File "/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/script.py", line 24, in tweaker\n    print(os.listdir(f\'{subdir}\'),flush=True)\nFileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: \'/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/script.in\'\n'
[2022-07-27 01:06:48,145] {{taskinstance.py:1128}} ERROR - Command '['/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/bin/python', '/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/script.py', '/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/script.in', '/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/script.out', '/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 966, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 307, in execute_callable
    string_args_filename))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 319, in _execute_in_subprocess
    close_fds=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/bin/python', '/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/script.py', '/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/script.in', '/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/script.out', '/tmp/venvuwoa1squ/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I don't see what's wrong with it .. help please?

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /tmp/venvuwoa1squ/script.in` Seems like the "script.in" file is missing...

Comment: If you are still working on your first DAG, i'd recommend you to move to Airflow 2. Airflow 1.10 is no longer supported and you are missing a bunch of nice features

Comment: Thanks but the company I'm working with is still on 1.10; not my decision.

Comment: Can you include the code for the callable `tweaker`?

Comment: Thanks but my organization doesn't support this operator I found; I'm using a workaround just installing the needed library on my dev instance for starts